# Use commandeventargs to a HTML Button control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button

I have a HTML control ie. Button. PFB Snippet

```
 <button type="button" id="Button7" onserverclick="btnSave_OnClick"
runat="server" commandname="SaveNext">
     Next 
 </button>
```

I am calling a same server side method from 2 different Button. I need to validate which button is clicked using CommandName in method.

Code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The problem is `EventArgs e` does not have CommandName . I changed method parameter to `commandeventargs e` which gives error as it requires `EventArgs e`

I am not preferring to change the HTML control to a `asp:button`.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server-side event handler, you can retrieve the `CommandName` from the attributes of the button:

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton btn = sender as HtmlButton;
    string commandName = btn.Attributes["CommandName"];
    ...
}
```